# C# User input a word eg( Hello ), how to i put hello into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

User input a word eg( `Hello` ), how do I put hello into an array? such that

```
array[1]=h
array[2]=e
array[3]=l
array[4]=l
array[5]=o
```

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."*

Answer (score 3):

Use the string method [ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) like this :

```
char[] input = "hello".ToCharArray();
```

If you have a lot of logic to do after, I'd recommend using a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead, which you can get with :

```
List<char> input = "hello".ToList();
```

And as a side note, `h` will be in `yourArray[0]` (or `.ElementAt(0)`) not `[1]`, since C# is 0-based; all indexes start at 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to do anything special to accomplish this. You can already access the characters in the string by using an indexer, like this:

`"Hello"[0]` will return "H", `"Hello"[1]` will return "e" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx):

```
char myArray[] = "Hello".ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below instead

```
char [] array = "Hello".ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
string[] a=Console.ReadLine() // Get String From user

char[]  myCharArray= a.ToCharArray();
```